# Working with Sessions - PHP

Tags: php, session

When working with Sessions, do you need to declare session_start() or ob_start() ? What are the advantages of doing so or not doing so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) must be used to store and read from the $_SESSION global.

[`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) is completely separate from sessions. ob_start() triggers output buffering which stores all output in a buffer for later use. When a PHP script ends, the buffer is automatically flushed to the user. Alternatively, you can fetch the contents of the buffer mid-execution and tweak the contents. See example below.

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
function callback($buffer)
{
  // replace all the apples with oranges
  return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing oranges to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a much more eloquent way of saying what I was trying to.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Makes much more sense now. Will check PHP.net in future :)

Answer (score 1):

**From PHP Manual**

[session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) -  Initialize session data

> SUMMARY:
>
> session_start() creates a session or
> resumes the current one based on the
> current session id that's being passed
> via a request, such as GET, POST, or a
> cookie.
>
> If you want to use a named session,
> you must call session_name() before
> calling session_start().
>
> session_start() will register internal
> output handler for URL rewriting when
> trans-sid is enabled. If a user uses
> ob_gzhandler or like with
> [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), the order of output
> handler is important for proper
> output. For example, user must
> register ob_gzhandler before session
> start.